# sorted function (list/tuple) working wrongly in reverse order

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

```
fn = sorted(finalDataSet,key = lambda x : x[1],reverse=True)
```

I got a result like this:

```
[('Hyperelastic', '8%'), ('Orthotropic', '26%'), ('Plastic', '23%'),
 ('Composites', '17%'), ('Anisotropic', '13%'), ('Thermal', '13%')]
```

Comment: Two things. Please add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and secondly what is the question?

Comment: You are sorting *strings*, not numbers. So `'8'` comes before `'2'`; it doesn't matter that there is another character `'6'` after that `'2'`, that's not how textual sorting works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be working correctly. You're sorting by strings and, alphabetically, '8%' is considered greater than '26%'. You may find this more useful as your `lambda`:

```
lambda x : float(x[1].strip('%'))
```

Comment: Given the percentages are all integer values, using `int` constructor instead of `float` might make sense.